# Mysql primary keys not coming in order

Tags: mysql, sql

`Select * from user_table;`

is giving the results in a order but when I am fetching only one column like

`Select user_id from user_table;`
then the user_ids are not coming in order.Please tell me the reasons or any help to solve this problem.Please observe the following links for result pages.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJ429.jpg
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sd1yS.jpg

Comment: Without an ORDER BY clause there will be no (consistently humanly discernible) order.

Comment: Please observe the below links. Here i did not use any order but still the result is like that.   http://i.stack.imgur.com/Sd1yS.jpg http://i.stack.imgur.com/rJ429.jpg

Comment: Yes, that's not my point. Rows in SQL represent 'unordered sets'. They have no order except that established by an ORDER BY clause. Without an ORDER BY clause, your results may appear arranged in a way that you consider to be 'ordered' but this is not guaranteed. Actually, it's a lot more complicated than that and relates to indexing and the internal storage mechanisms of the engine, but essentially, if you want results ORDERED in a certain way, then you have to use an ORDER BY clause, or rearrange the resulting array in your application level code.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user_id from user_table order by user_id ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Part of the "SQL contract" is that there is *no default order* to rows that you `SELECT`.  The database engine is free to present them in any order that is convenient for it to do.  This order is likely to change based on the columns you return (to take advantage of instances in which the entire query can be satisfied by reading from indexes only) and can also change based on the `WHERE` clause used to retrieve the records.  It may also change from day to day or version to version for no apparent reason.

In order to be confident in the order of the rows returned, you *must* supply an ORDER BY clause with sufficient specificity to guarantee exactly the order you want.